# Why is the #include directive not necessary in C#?

Tags: c#, include

Why is the #include directive not necessary in C#? Is this due to the fact that C# has a more developed/inclusive/restrictive compilation process vs the raw nature of C/C++ preprocessor, compiler, linker, etc.? (i.e. you're developing in Visual Studio for C#).

I'm just curious how the compilation process knows where to look for additional classes.

Edit: I realize you wouldn't need the actual #include statement in C# because that doesn't make sense. However, I'm more curious as to how your C# program is aware of the existence of other classes without any kind of indicator.
Thanks,

Comment: Because all the `.cs` files you're compiling are known by the compiler, so they don't have to include each other.  The file names are passed directly to the compiler.  It's actually the same in C++ with `.cpp` files only in that case it's the linker that takes care of putting it all together.

Comment: Direct answer - C# is not C. Forget about C when programming C# and don't ask questions "Why?" (simply imaging how many of such questions you **can ask**). More concrete answer - C# doesn't use H files, doesn't look for `#include` to find files, etc., instead you defining where to look for classes using project files and `using`. For more information read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2134017/1997232), might be useful.

Comment: @Sinatr So my experience with the 'using' keyword in C++ is that it is used for type resolution. It appears to be similar in C#. However, the 'using' keyword does nothing as far as actually bringing in code to make it accessible within your class. In C++ you would use the #include directive to bring in class defs, function prototypes, etc. to notify the compiler to look for something that should be defined somewhere. However, in C#, the IDE does this for you? Thus you don't need the #include directive?

Comment: Honestly I have no idea what is *type resolution* in C++. It doesn't matter what `using` is in C++. It only matter what [`using` directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) is in C#, right? As for [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/yh598w02.aspx), it's another C# thing, don't try to look for similarities in languages you know, simply read what it is and use it. And .. forget about `#include`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# has something similar. To use classes in other libraries etc. you need to add a reference to the assembly and then use the `using` key word followed by the name of the reference like this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic
```

This example namespace would enable me to access classes such as `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` etc.

For more info on references see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh708954.aspx).

Comment: Could you expand on the 'you need to add a reference to the assembly' part? Correct me if I'm wrong, but you could still have access to all of those classes without using the 'using' keyword, it's just that you would have to fully specifying the name (i.e. System.Colelctions.Generic.Dicitionary<TKey, TValue>) However, I'm confused as to how you make your source code aware of other classes. Do you do this by making sure to 'add a reference to the assembly'? What makes this reference? The IDE?

Comment: @Teague - in Visual Studio under a project there's a heading called 'References'. Right click on that and click 'Add Reference'. This enables you to add a reference to an assembly that contains the classes you want to use. The IDE then creates the reference for you. Once this has been added you don't NEED to add the `using` key word and you could just use the fully specified name instead, but obviously that's more cumbersome.

Comment: Thank you sr28. This is what I was attempting to get at. The reason you don't need to use the #include directive in C# is because it is handled by settings in the IDE, not the source files themselves.

Comment: @Teague - It has nothing to do with the IDE.  The same would apply if you were compiling from the command line.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway How does the compiler know where to look for .cs files?